# What's the meaning of the word "shower" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

[image]google dictionary def for "douche"
**a shower** of water.
"I felt better for taking a daily douche"

What does the word **shower** mean in this context?
is it...
a. A bath in which the water is sprayed on the bather in fine streams from a showerhead, usually secured overhead: *take a shower*.(source:TFD)...?

Seems weird that "douche" would be a synonym for that. Never heard of a lady during a social gathering to suddenly say "sorry guys, I'll just take a quick douche and be back with you in no time" :D

Also, I know that "douche" means
a. A stream of water, often containing medicinal or cleansing agents, that is applied to a body part or cavity for hygienic or therapeutic purposes.(source:TFD)

But I can't find a defintion of "**shower**" that would fit that definition(a stream of water).

Please help, I don't want my social life to deteriorate after making a linguistic mistake at a hang :)

**Edit: The image I added doesn't remind me a thing called shower.**

Comment: _Douche_ is the French word for _shower_ (as a means of washing yourself). I don't know why you can't find a [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shower) of _shower_. In English, the French word is used in the medical sense you describe. But I can't imagine why you think anyone would 'suddenly' take either in the middle of a social gathering.

Comment: Kate Bunting I tough shower could mean "A stream of water" as in the definition of the word "douche" but was unable to find anything matching that definition. Oh and i didn't think somebody would take a shower in the middle of a room where there are people, I only meant they could tell somebody the will retire to a bathroom for a quick shower and get back to a party :)

Comment: Even that would be rather odd - surely you would have taken a shower _before_ the party? Of course, we also speak of a shower of rain (when it rains for a short time) or of water or some other liquid being scattered in drops. A _stream_ of water isn't a shower.

Comment: So you stopped reading the definition after the first sentence? You didn't look at any other definitions?

Comment: CollenV What makes you think that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake to think that translation between two languages is as simple as substituting one word for another. Context changes words in almost any language. A word in English that has multiple meanings may not share *all* of those meanings with the same word in another language.

"Douche" is the French word for what most English-speaking people call "a shower" - that is a plumbed utility that *sprays* water for cleaning purposes. I wouldn't say that a shower was a '*stream*' of water as you described - a stream is a single jet of water, such as what comes out of a tap, or faucet.

As you noted, "douche" is also used in English (what is sometimes called a 'loanword' or 'borrow-word' from French) for a specific kind of hygiene device. The fact that "douche" has this specific use in English is the main reason why we would not use it interchangeably with 'shower' in English. It is also important to note that loanwords do not always retain their original meaning - an example being 'cul-de-sac', which in French literally means "bottom of the bag", but is used in English to mean a road which leads to a 'dead-end'.

The English word "shower" has its own unique etymology and is also used to describe light rain. The French word "douche" is not used for rain.

Comment: For me a shower is a device you've got in your bathroom. I take a shower everyday, but I would never say "It's a shower of water" I might say "a bathtub full of water". If douche means the same as shower in the google's definition, can I from now on start saying, I'm gonna take a douche(and not a shower)?

Comment: @StaticBounce If you are learning English, I would advise using a trustworthy English dictionary for definitions, not Google. I use Cambridge for British English, and Websters if I need to check a US English definition. Neither of these define 'douche' as a shower.

Comment: Google uses OxfordDictionaries, I'm not talking about a google translator FYI. Kindle built-in dictionary uses the same one as well.